# Remove the [name] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tagging

Should we keep the [name](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/name) tag?
The tag  doesn't itself contain any information. Almost any post can have it.
There's only [one question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/202/58) marked with this tag and the tag is useless there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Both the [name](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/name) tag, and the [type](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type) tag that the question were tagged with, have been removed. They're both completely meta, provide no useful information to the question, and shouldn't be kept around.

Based on what the question was asking, I've *created* the [terminology](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag to go on it.